# Recurrence Relations - Concept Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find the first five terms of the sequence as defined by these relations and the initial terms.

$A_n = nA_{n-1} + n^2 A_{n-2}$

$A_0 = 1$

$A_1 = 1$

$A_2 = 1\cdot 1 + 1^2 \cdot 1 = 2$

$A_3 = 3 \cdot 2 + 3 ^ 2 \cdot 1 = 15$

$A_4 = 4 \cdot 15 + 4 ^ 2 \cdot 2 = 96$

Answer sheet says I'm wrong. Where did I mess up here?

Comment: Is capital $N$ the same as lowercase $n$? If yes, $A_2$ is already wrong..

Comment: The mistake you made is visible already in $A_2$. Instead of $N=2$, you used $N=1$ for some reason.

Comment: Edited just now.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$A_2 = 1\cdot 1 + 1^2 \cdot 1 = 2$ is not correct. We have $A_2=2A_1+4A_0=6.$